# How can I resolve the error I am getting in web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

```
**web-api**
```

As u can see I have to develop different api . For this I have created a MasterController. But I am getting an problem. I am using Postman for testing and I am getting the following problem. Please help me to resolve this issue. I am getting multiple match points. Please help me resolve the issue.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VENUS.HRMS.API.Filters;
using VENUS.HRMS.DATA.Data;
using VENUS.HRMS.DATA.Models;

namespace VENUS.HRMS.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class MasterController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [AuthorizationFilter]
        public IEnumerable<TblMstEmpRole> Get()
        {
            var emprole = new EmpRoleData().GetMstEmpRole();

            return emprole;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AuthorizationFilter]
        public IEnumerable<TblMstState> GetState()
        {
          var state = new StateData().GetMstState();

            return state;

        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AuthorizationFilter]
        public IEnumerable<TblMstCity> GetCity()
        {
            var city = new CityData().GetMstCity();

            return city;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is exactly what error says: `The request matched multiple endpoints`

Remember when calling an API, the function name does not matter. The function name is only for *"Internal"* use within your C# applicaiton. The name of the API endpoint correlates to it's route. This route is set with either the `[Route()]` attribute or within the `[HttpGet()]` attribute.

For example you have 3 functions:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<TblMstEmpRole> Get()

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<TblMstState> GetState()

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<TblMstCity> GetCity()
```

The full route for these three functions respectively are:

```
Get --> /Master/
Get --> /Master/
Get --> /Master/
```

Yes all thee are the same. And that is the exact issue you are having. To fix this change the Route for your endpoints like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<TblMstEmpRole> Get()

[HttpGet("State")]
public IEnumerable<TblMstState> GetState()

[HttpGet("City")]
public IEnumerable<TblMstCity> GetCity()
```

Now the routes will look like this:

```
Get --> /Master/
Get --> /Master/State
Get --> /Master/City
```

The rule is:

> You can only have one route name per Http operation.

---

### Different HTTP Methods

`[HttpGet]` is one of the attributes which has a `GET` method, however, there are many other methods such as `POST`, `HEAD`, `PUT`, `OPTIONS`, `DELETE`, `CONNECT`, `TRACE` and `PATCH`.

To utilize them through an API endpoint all you need to do is add it to the function. All the attributes have the `[Http***]` format. Example Post and Put will be:

```
[HttpPost]
[HttoPut]
```

And has mentioned a little above, you can only have one *Route* for each method. See examples below:

```
// PATH: GET --> /Master/
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<TblMstEmpRole> GETGet()

// PATH: POST --> /Master/
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<TblMstEmpRole> POSTGet()
```

The above example is **VALID**. Even though we have two functions with the same route, they do have different Http Methods and as such are uniquely identifiable.

### Why Different Methods

Each method has it's own quirks and uses. Depending on the method, some things are allowed and some are not. When a client makes a query to a server and sends something, that is called a `Http Request`. The method for either getting or setting it is the `Http Method`, example GET, POST, PUT...

A Http Request has the following structure:

- Headers
- Parameters
- Body
- Footer

If we were to use the `GET` method, then you are telling the endpoint that it should ignore the `Body` of the request.

If we were to use the `HEAD` method then we are telling the endpoint that we are only interested in the `Headers` section of the request.

Now to figure out which to use and when can be tricky, but as a basic rule of thumb you can use this:

- GET - You are only fetching data and not sending anything in the body
- POST - When you are creating something in the database or sending data in the body
- PUT - Similar to Post, but only when you are updating something
- DELETE - When you are removing something.

These are the basic 4 any beginner to intermediate should be aware of. For more information on what method to use see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: thanks for the solution. Can u tell me that how can we insert the data from code to db and create method as POST for the above

Comment: @VikasRaj, I've added how to use a POST method as well as when. As for how to insert data from the code to the database there are many different ways. Easy & Intermediate: Use Dapper (https://dapper-tutorial.net/). Intermediate to Advance: Use Entity Framework (https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/07/29/entity-framework-core-api)